# Bootstrap: table-hover leaves trace when removed by JS on Safari 9.1

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm new to HTML/JS and trying to build a simple Bootstrap page with two tabs, one with a table and another with assorted textfields, buttons etc.

The problem is, when I view this page on Safari 9.1, the seperator line of the `hover-table` seems to leave some "residue" when switching tabs, even though I make sure to delete the elements related to the table in the process of switching. When I switch back to the tab with the table, the line doesn't render properly. This doesn't happen on Opera.

Here's a screenshot of the said "residue". (The grey line is not supposed to be there.):
[image: Here's a screenshot of the said "residue"]

Line not rendering properly when switched back, see line segment between "send" and "time":
[image: Line not rendering properly when switched back, see line segment between "send" and "time"]

I've also included a snippet of the code that produces the problem. Is this bug caused by my code or browser/bootstrap? Can I solve it, if so how?

Thank you.

```js
var sendComponents =
    '<div style="margin-top: 15px"><div style="display: inline-block; float: left;">' +
    '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button</button>' +
    '</div></div>';

var table =
    '<table class="table table-hover" style="table-layout: fixed" id="messageTable">' +
    '<thead><tr><th class="col-md-1">Send</th><th class="col-md-2">Time</th>' +
    '<th class="col-md-5">Message</th> </tr> </thead> <tbody id="tableBody">' +
    '</tbody></table>';

function inboxBtnAction() {
    document.getElementById("inboxBtn").className = "btn btn-default active";
    document.getElementById("sendBtn").className = "btn btn-default";

    inboxTab();
}

function sendBtnAction() {
    document.getElementById("inboxBtn").className = "btn btn-default";
    document.getElementById("sendBtn").className = "btn btn-default active";

    sendTab();
}

function sendTab() {

    var centerDiv = document.getElementById("centerDiv");

    while (centerDiv.firstChild) {
        centerDiv.removeChild(centerDiv.firstChild);
    }
    document.getElementById("centerDiv").innerHTML = sendComponents;

}

function inboxTab() {

    var centerDiv = document.getElementById("centerDiv");

    while (centerDiv.firstChild) {
        centerDiv.removeChild(centerDiv.firstChild);
    }
    document.getElementById("centerDiv").innerHTML = table;

}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <title>Messaging System Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <div style="margin-top: 100px">
        <div id="wrapper" style="text-align: center; margin-bottom: 15px">
            <div class="btn-group" role="group" style="display: inline-block">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default active" id="inboxBtn" onclick="inboxBtnAction()">Inbox
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="sendBtn" onclick="sendBtnAction()">Send</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container" id="centerDiv">
            <table class="table table-hover" style="table-layout: fixed" id="messageTable">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="col-md-1">Sender</th>
                    <th class="col-md-2">Time</th>
                    <th class="col-md-5">Message</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="tableBody">
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```